# Subsonic error: Unknown column 't0.CartQuantity' in 'field list'

Tags: subsonic3

I added a custom property to a generated class from the database using a partial class and for some reason everytime I query my table it tries to look for the custom property as a column in the database and that's when I get this error, is there a way to tell subsonic that my property is not a column in the database?

I'm using Mysql by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the SubsonicIgnore attribute on my property and it fixed the issue.